How to query the GPU model on a machine using ipmitool?
I want to query the GPU model on a server using the BMC. In the web-based BMC management page, I can find that there are two NVIDIA A10 GPUs in the machine's PCIe devices through the "Asset Information" section.
How can I query this information using the ipmitool tool?
I have tried the following command, but only monitoring information such as hardware power consumption is displayed, without device model information.
ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IP_ADDRESS> -U <USERNAME> -P <PASSWORD> sdr


sdr is the Print Sensor Data Repository entries and readings command.
Use the fru command (Print built-in FRU and scan SDR for FRU locators):
ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IP_ADDRESS> -U <USERNAME> -P <PASSWORD> fru

I have no experience with such devices like GPU, but Chassis, Motherboard, CPU, HDD, RAM etc can be obtained using this command.
